# Compiling list of empty rows and hiding them in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

As the name function reveals, I need to hide some rows that are blank from the column 4 forward but doing it one by one makes the process very slow so my idea is to get all the values into a list and then feed this list to the hideRows function and hide the rows all at once. It's giving me an error but honestly I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

> 

```js
function HidingYoMama() {
   
for (var i=8;i<415;i++) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var targetRow = ss.getRange(i,4,1,ss.getLastColumn());
  var isBlank = targetRow.isBlank();
  var title = ss.getRange(i,1,1,3).isBlank();
  var hideThisRows = [];
    if (title == false) {
      if(isBlank == true) {
        var result = hideThisRows.push(targetRow[i]);
        Logger.log(result);
  }
  }
  }
 
 var hideThem = ss.hideRows(hideThisRows);
 Logger.log(hideThem); #Those rows are out of bounds. (line 187, file "Code")

}
```

Comment: Well? What is `hideThisRows`when you attempt to use them? Didnt you debug your script?

Comment: targetRow[i] ? Are you certain?

Comment: @tehhowch honestly I'm totally new to the Scripts or any scripting language for that matter, so I lack the knowledge to understand where I'm failing. Looking at documentation I couldn't understand how to achieve my goal or debug my code.

Comment: @RoumelisGeorge Yes. I'm trying to check each row after column 4 because they all have titles and then values after column 4 so I wanna check if they are empty only after that. Sorry, I thought you were talking about the variable. About targetRow[i], not really, I don't understand very well how to push the values to the empty list. If you can help me understand better I'd be grateful ;)

Comment: A simple start is to move things that need doing only once outside the for loop. Use the "bug" icon to run in debug mode, and spend some time reading about "breakpoints"

Comment: @tehhowch Will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the documentation for the hideRow(s) method. So if you look below you will see the method accepts two parameters. rowIndex (From what row should I start hiding) and numRows accepts how many rows down from starting point should I hide.

### hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)

Both of those parameters accept single integer values. An example would be:
sheet.hideRows(1,3) This will start hiding from the first row and hide the following 3 rows.)

You are getting an error because you are effectively trying to push "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" into something that accepts "1".

I tested this code on 150 lines (with one blank value) it seemed to work well. (Execution time was 12 seconds.) Hope this helps.

```
function hideRows() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()


  for (var i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if(sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1).isBlank()) {
     sheet.hideRows(i)

  }

}
}
```

Comment: my sheet is huge and with quite a few columns so with this method takes a lot of time and goes one by one and hides them. I need something that collects all the rows at once and then hide them all at once

Comment: Hi I get that, and as you can you can't push an array into hideRows. You will need to do it one by one. You could potentially sort your data and then hide your rows, but I am guessing that is not something you want to do. Hence the above code and comments.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sorry for the terrible grammar above. Was helping out with testing and trying to comment at the same time... :D